# Chat history not saved in azure blob storage through MS Teams

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-blob-storage

Chat transcript is not saved in the azure blob storage container when the flow is triggered through MS Teams.
Below is the code that I'm using to save the chat transcript in the container of blob storage.

```
//for saving chat transcripts in blob storage
const { AzureBlobTranscriptStore  } = require('botbuilder-azure');
const { TranscriptLoggerMiddleware } = require('botbuilder-core');

// Get blob service configuration as defined in .bot file
//const blobStorageConfig = botConfig.findServiceByNameOrId(BLOB_CONFIGURATION);
// The transcript store has methods for saving and retrieving bot conversation transcripts.
let transcriptStore = new AzureBlobTranscriptStore({storageAccountOrConnectionString: process.env.BLOB_STRING,
                                                    containerName: process.env.BLOB_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME
                                                    });
// Create the middleware layer responsible for logging incoming and outgoing activities
// into the transcript store.
var transcriptMiddleware = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(transcriptStore);
adapter.use(transcriptMiddleware);
```

Whereas this code works fine with web app and emulator.

Version used-
 "botbuilder-azure": "^4.7.2"
  botbuilder-core": "4.7.2"

Comment: I assume you've debugged to confirm that the BLOB_STRING and BLOB_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME are populated correctly?

Comment: yes hilton,those are correct .

Comment: We are investigating this issue internally

Comment: I've just tried the AzureBlobTranscriptStore with a Teams bot, and it is working as expected.  Have you tried debugging locally, and watch the debug console for errors?

Comment: Teams transcript id was being stored with some extra characters on top of the actual conv id's .Hence the confusion.This is not an issue. Thanks anyways.